# Sending printer an attachment with phpmailer causes blank first page

Tags: php, printing, phpmailer

I have been working on using phpmailer to send a pdf attachment to printers. Everything seems to work correctly except that each time it sends the pdf to the printer it prints a blank page and then the attachment.

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.******.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '****@****.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '***';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Subject = 'PDF Attached'
$mail->AltBody = 'A pdf has been attached.';
$mail->addAttachment($filename); // attachment
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
$mail->addAddress("***************@hpeprint.com");
$mail->msgHTML("");
$mail->send();
```

If I send an email manually through my own email it doesn't not print the extra page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I have my doubts that phpmailer is modifying your PDF file. What happens if, instead of mailing it, you output it to the browser? `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='test.pdf'"); readfile($filename);`

Comment: My guess is that the printer prints one page with the email body, and another with the attachment. What happens when you remove `$mail->msgHTML` and `$mail->AltBody`?

Answer (score 1):

`msgHTML` also sets `AltBody`, and since you're passing in an empty string, you'll and up with an empty message body (which you've suppressed the error for). Since you've not set `Body` to anything, nor called `isHTML`, by default it's not going to send a `multipart/alternative` message. I suggest cutting it back to basics:

```
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.******.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '****@****.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '***';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Subject = 'PDF Attached'
$mail->addAttachment($filename); // attachment
$mail->AllowEmpty = true;
$mail->addAddress("***************@hpeprint.com");
$mail->send();
```

I hope you've got some error handling wrapped around all this...

Comment: that is correct. I don’t want to send any body message. Just the attachment to the printer. I assumed setting the body =“” would leave body blank. Is that not correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct, but that’s not what you did - you set `AltBody`.